# Maven Surefire plugin "Error occured in starting fork, check output in log"

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

I get the following error

```
BUILD ERROR
Error occured in starting fork, check output in log
```

when using Maven 2.2.1 and Surefire plugin 2.11 while running junit test cases.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Launch your build with debug logs : add -X to your command line.

Comment: This may also be due to the issue SUREFIRE-870, which is fixed in the 2.12.1 version of the plugin.

Comment: Actual problem for recent versions (2.20.1)

Comment: Possible duplicate question: [Strategy for debugging surefire “The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ?”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20642673/741249)

Comment: had issues - upgraded surefire plugin to 2.22.2, worked ok.

Comment: For reference, I had this issue when using an old version of jacoco with java 11, and having --illegal-access=permit defined as a argline to surefire. Upgrading to jacoco 0.8.5 and removing the argline configuration fixed my issue.

Answer (score 34):

You need to setup surefire plugin to use `<forkMode>once</forkMode>` like this:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <forkMode>once</forkMode>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: the option is deprecated, any updated combination to solve the issue?

Comment: I fixed it with <forkCount>0</forkCount> (instead of the deprecated forkMode).

Comment: notice that forkMode once is NOT the same as forkCount 0.From https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html, the equivalent would be forkCount 1 with reuseForks true. However, seems forkCount 0 fixes the issue.

Comment: with this you loose jacoco coverage on sonar...any other ideas because i m in the same situation. thanks

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue on my local with maven-surefire-plugin plugin.

After adding `<forkCount>0</forkCount>` to maven-surefire-plugin plugin it worked for me.

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m ${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
                <forkCount>0</forkCount>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me worked as @Ganesh Thorat.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.5</version>
  <configuration>
      <forkCount>0</forkCount>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score -1):

encountered the same issue

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

set "**useSystemClassLoader as false"**