# maven jacoco: not generating code coverage report

Tags: java, maven, code-coverage, jacoco

I am trying to setup `jacoco` for my project's code coverage

My project is based on `Java 1.8`

Here is how things look in my project's `pom.xml`

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.10.201208310627</version>
        <configuration>
            <output>file</output>
            <append>true</append>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>jacoco-site</id>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Then I run  `mvn test` and see the following

```
$ mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building pennyapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.5.10.201208310627:prepare-agent (jacoco-initialize) @ pennyapp ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/Users/harit/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.5.10.201208310627/org.jacoco.agent-0.5.10.201208310627-runtime.jar=destfile=/Users/harit/code/idea/pennyapp/target/jacoco.exec,append=true,output=file
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ pennyapp ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ pennyapp ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/harit/code/idea/pennyapp/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ pennyapp ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/harit/code/idea/pennyapp/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ pennyapp ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/harit/code/idea/pennyapp/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @ pennyapp ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/harit/code/idea/pennyapp/shippable/testresults
[INFO] Using configured provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
objc[13225]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Running HelloTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.1 sec - in HelloTest

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.523 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-08-19T17:56:33-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/119M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and then I run `mvn jacoco:report` and I see

```
$ mvn jacoco:report
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building pennyapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.5.10.201208310627:report (default-cli) @ pennyapp ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.176 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-08-19T17:56:51-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/112M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then I look at `target/site/jacoco/index.html` and see the following
[image]

**Question**
- What is incorrect in the configuration?
- How can I generate report?

Thanks

Comment: Any particular reason why you are using an outdated version of the JaCoCo plugin? For Java 8 support, you have to use at least version 0.7.0 (see [changelog](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/changes.html)).

Comment: running old version of `jacoco` was problem. It is fixed after that

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Any particular reason why you are using an outdated version of the JaCoCo plugin? For Java 8 support, you have to use at least version 0.7.0 (see [changelog](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/changes.html)).

In your configuration, the report goal is bound to the verify phase, so running `mvn test` won't generate any report because it does not run the verify phase ([test phase comes before verify](http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html)). You have to use `mvn verify` to execute tests and generate the report.

The JaCoCo project provides example Maven configurations. You can try "[this POM file for a JAR project runs JUnit tests under code coverage and creates a coverage report](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/examples/build/pom.xml)".

Comment: I was using mvn test. It worked when I used mvn verify

Answer (score 31):

JaCoco Maven Plugin is overriding Surefire argLine, in case you also need to override argLine, be sure to keep argLine variable:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.19.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <argLine>-Xmx1024M ${argLine}</argLine> 
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Note you can change this property name, as describe in the [jacoco plugin documentation](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html#propertyName).

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue.
The problem was that i had add the jacoco plugin inside the `<plugins>` that was listed inside `<pluginManagment>` tag.

```
  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
       ...
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>jacoco-report</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
...
       
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

After add `<plugins>` as direct child of `<build>` everything works fine.

```
<build>
....
 <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>jacoco-report</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
...
<build>
```

Comment: It is strange but saved me lot.

Comment: Good to hear that @laksys.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

```
mvn clean install
mvn site
```

Even though the minimum code coverage was not met and `mvn clean install` failed, the `mvn site` build succeeded and created the coverage report at:

```
.../target/site/jacoco/index.html
```

Answer (score 7):

Following works for me without any issues

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-report</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>                   
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

NOTE : phase is 'test' in-order to generate the report once tests are executed

Comment: thx. after adding <phase>test</phase> 
site path generated on mvn clean install

Comment: For me, <phase>test</phase> is the key, site folder is now genreated when running 'mvn test'

Answer (score 2):

Had similar problem i dont know the root cause but avoiding in build resolved problem

```
<pluginManagement>
```

Following the pom that worked out for me

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>SampleSpring</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <name>SampleSpring</name>
        <description>Demo project for SampleSpring</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
            <start-class>com.example.spring.SampleSpringApplication</start-class>

            <jacoco.version>0.8.3</jacoco.version>
            <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
            <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
            <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
            <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>

        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Testing -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Testing -->


        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                </plugin>

                <!--jacoco plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.8.5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <output>file</output>
                        <append>true</append>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jacoco-site</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <!--jacoco plugin end -->

                <!--Sonarqube plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.0.1398</version>
                </plugin>
                <!--Sonarqube plugin end -->

            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before trying the other workarounds, first check *“Toggle ‘Skip Test’ mode”* is not active on the Maven toolbar in IntelliJ IDEA.

[image]