# JaCoCo not generating jacoco.exec until after skipping JaCoCo execution

Tags: maven, jacoco

I'm having trouble generating AHP reports via JaCoCo in one of my modules. When the build starts, I see JaCoCo correctly setting argLine with:

```
[INFO] jacoco.agent.argLine set to -javaagent:<...>/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.2.201409121644/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.2.201409121644-runtime.jar=destfile=<...>/target/jacoco.exec
```

However, the .exec hasn't been created yet by the time maven tries to run JaCoCo:

```
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file:<...>/target/jacoco.exec
```

The jacoco.exec does eventually get created, after maven has skipped JaCoCo execution. Therefore, I can still generate AHP reports, if I re-run the build without cleaning.

I've seen in various other questions that I need to be careful using Maven Surefire with JaCoCo. However, I don't explicitly use argLine in my Surefire plugins, or in any plugin for that matter. I'm starting to wonder if one of the other plugins is hijacking the argLine parameter automatically like JaCoCo does.

Here is a list of all plugins used:

- jacoco-maven-plugin
- vertx-maven-plugin
- maven-resources-plugin
- maven-dependency-plugin
- maven-surefire-plugin
- maven-failsafe-plugin
- maven-surefire-report-plugin
- maven-assembly-plugin

I do see one suspicious message in the build output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ <module> ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
```

I'm not sure if that's relevant, but it appears twice before the Skipping message, and doesn't appear in a module where JaCoCo works properly.

Any ideas?

*edit - Here's the jacoco config

```
    <plugins>
        <...>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        jacoco-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [0.7.2.201409121644,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

I'm not sure exactly what that plugin management part is doing, but commenting it out doesn't fix anything. I've also tried putting the JaCoCo plugin config above the surefire/failsafe config in case order mattered for plugins sharing the same goals, but that didn't help either.

*edit 2 - Looks like the problem was surefire's includes. Commenting them out somehow fixes JaCoCo's .exec generation, and JaCoCo works properly.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- <includes>
                    <include>**/unit/**/*Test*.java</include>
                </includes> -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: If the problem continues despite of applying the workarounds, you may have a look at my answer on [maven jacoco: not generating code coverage report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395255/maven-jacoco-not-generating-code-coverage-report/71661614#71661614).

Answer (score 47):

Just an addition to the answers already given.
It could happen that in your maven-surefire-plugin configuration you already use the argLine configuration to override something like the memory used. If you do so the argline set by jacoco-maven-plugin will not be used failing to generate the jacoco report.
In this case assign a property name to the jacoco-maven-plugin config and then reference it in your maven-surefire-plugin argLine parameter.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.9</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- prepare agent for measuring unit tests -->
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-unit-tests</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <append>true</append>
                        <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                        <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when unit tests are run. -->
                        <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

[...]

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <printSummary>false</printSummary>
                <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                <forkCount>3</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                <argLine>${surefireArgLine} -Xmx1024m -noverify</argLine>                  
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks! It didn't quite work for me. I had to use @{surefireArgLine}, i.e. late property evaluation: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/faq.html#late-property-evaluation

Comment: Thank you so much @Massimo, argLine was the solution also for me!

Comment: Great! This was exactly my case: jacoco stopped generating `jacoco.exec` and `target/site` after I added memory to `surefire-plugin`, since the heavy test was crashing.

Comment: Finally got some where with this problem! Thank you - the surefire arguments is certainly sending me in the right direction.

Answer (score 6):

To solve this issue I would use the following three steps:

1. Determine which plugin execution is producing the `jacoco.exec` file. To do that, you could run Maven with debug logging enabled (`mvn -X`) and look for the `jacoco.agent.argLine` property name or its value in the output. You could also have a look at the effective POM (`mvn help:effective-pom`) in case the relevant configuration comes from the parent POM. Note that my guess is that it's an execution of the `maven-failsafe-plugin`.
2. Determine the phase that plugin is executed in. E.g. for `maven-failsafe-plugin` this would likely be `integration-test`.
3. Change the configuration of the JaCoCo plugin so that the `report` goal is executed later in the [build lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). E.g. if the `jacoco.exec` file is produced in the `integration-test` phase, you could execute the `report` goal in the `post-integration-test` phase.

Comment: Thanks, those command line arguments were really helpful to me in understanding what maven does behind the scenes. Nothing really stood out to me, so I just started commenting out plugins until I discovered the following. * edit - put the discovery in edit 2 on question

Answer (score 5):

In my case the solution was what @massimo mentioned, i was overriding memory values inside `<surefireArgLine>` tag, after i removed the tag it started generating the report and showed code coverage.

Answer (score 2):

I did not find any solution, but I did the following:

**mvn clean jacoco:prepare-agent install**
create file jacoco.exec, but execute mvn sonar:sonar not create File.

Solution:

Step 1:
**mvn clean jacoco:prepare-agent install**

Step 2:
**copy file jacoco.exec from /src/main/resources**
Step 3:

**Add next plugin on pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${basedir}/target/</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>
                                        ${basedir}/src/main/resources/ </directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>jacoco.exec</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>cp1252</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Step 4:
**mvn clean install**

Step 5:

**mvn sonar:sonar**

### READY

Add my section Plugins

```
<pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>cp1252</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${basedir}/target/</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>
                                        ${basedir}/src/main/resources/ </directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>jacoco.exec</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-folder</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>cp1252</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Plugin Sonar -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.6.201602180812</version>

                <configuration>
                    <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <destFile>${basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                            <dataFile>${basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-site</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

Answer (score 2):

for me one of the reason for exec file not getting generated is when i placed the prepare-agent , prepare-package goals inside plugin section of pluginManagement

when i tried the same outside pluginManagement , i was sucessfully able to run the same and jacoco-exec file was generated using mvn clean install command

my pomfile is as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>mmt</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacoco</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>jacoco</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <argLine>-Xms256m -Xmx1524m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Duser.language=en</argLine>
 </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.20.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>


<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem where jacoco plugin was added to parent pom, and jacoco.exec file was generating for one of the sub modules. I had to remove the argLine arguments of maven surefire plugin, then it got generated.

Comment: the argLine argument was removed from the sub modules which was not generating the exec file.