# 0% code coverage on espresso tests with JaCoCo and Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso, jacoco

In my JaCoCo code coverage reports for my espresso tests, all lines and branches are missed. I am using JaCoCo in an Android application which is built with gradle 1.5.0.

My gradle configuration:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

android {
   buildTypes {
      debug {
         testCoverageEnabled = true
      }
   }
}

jacoco {
   version '0.7.5.201505241946'
}
```

I followed this blog post: [Test coverage report for Android application](http://blog.wittchen.biz.pl/test-coverage-report-for-android-application/).

When I run `createDebugCoverageReport`, the report is generated in the correct folder (build/reports/coverage/flavor/debug/index.html). However, when I open the coverage report, my code coverage is 0% on every instructions and branches. Everything is "missed".

[image]

First I thought that the problem could be the location of the source code and test code, but they are located in `/src/main/java/` and `/src/androidTest/java/`

Anyone has an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this problem?

Comment: OMG, for me it was the Samsung phone and the emulator works fine!

Answer (score 2):

As per my experience if any one test case fails then we get coverage report with 0% make sure all your tests passes

Answer (score 1):

My personal experience with Jacoco has not been good. It doesn't cover properly, and when it does it doesn't update the coverage as new tests are added.

I have just removed it, there doesn't seem to be support for Jacoco.

For your question though, according to [@kolargol00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3901701/kolargol00):

### [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25396164/4180965)

Any particular reason why you are using an outdated version of the JaCoCo plugin? For Java 8 support, you have to use at least version 0.7.0 (see [changelog](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/changes.html)).

In your configuration, the report goal is bound to the verify phase, so running `mvn test` won't generate any report because it does not run the verify phase ([test phase comes before verify](http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html)). You have to use `mvn verify` to execute tests and generate the report.

The JaCoCo project provides example Maven configurations. You can try "[this POM file for a JAR project runs JUnit tests under code coverage and creates a coverage report](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/examples/build/pom.xml)".