# Gradle Jacoco plugin not generating reports

Tags: java, gradle, jacoco

Java 8 and Gradle 4.6 here. I'm trying to configure my Gradle build to use the [Jacoco Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html) but am having some difficulty. I've already got it working with Checkstyle and Findbugs, such that running `./gradlew clean build` invokes the Checkstyle and Findbugs tasks because they're dependencies of the `check` task.

I'm now trying to get Jacoco working such that:

1. It excludes my `com.me.myapp.domain.model` package and all of its contents; and
2. It fails my build if code coverage on the non-excluded classes falls below 70%; and
3. Pass or fail, I want an HTML version of the Jacoco report generated under the `build/` directory; and
4. **Ideally** I could just use the same Gradle command invocation of `./gradlew clean build` to get Jacoco working like this

My best attempt thus far:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'checkstyle'
    id 'findbugs'
    id 'jacoco'
}

dependencies {
    compile(
        'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.0.12.Final'
        ,'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.10'
        ,'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.10'
        ,'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.0'
    )

    testCompile(
        'junit:junit:4.12'
    )
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

checkstyle {
    config = rootProject.resources.text.fromFile('buildConfig/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml')
    toolVersion = '8.11'
}

tasks.withType(FindBugs) {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        html.enabled true
    }
}

findbugs {
    excludeFilter = file('buildConfig/findbugs/findbugs-exclude.xml')
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.enabled true
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it,
                exclude: [
                    'com/me/myapp/domain/model/**'
                ]
            )
        })
    }
}

jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    violationRules {
        rule {
            limit {
                minimum = 0.7
            }

            failOnViolation true
        }
    }
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.1"
}

// to run coverage verification during the build (and fail when appropriate)
check.dependsOn jacocoTestCoverageVerification
```

When I run `./gradlew clean build` with the following `build.gradle` above (^^^) Jacoco *does* fail the build if my coverage is less than 70%. **However** it does not generate any HTML report for me, which is not helpful at all in terms of fixing it.

**Any ideas?**

Comment: Are the CSV or XML reports generated if you enable them?

Comment: Thanks @mascha (+1) but **no**, when I enable XML/CSV reporting they aren't generated either with `./gradlew clean build`.

Comment: If the problem continues despite of applying the workarounds, you may have a look at my answer on [maven jacoco: not generating code coverage report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395255/maven-jacoco-not-generating-code-coverage-report/71661614#71661614).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please note, that the Gradle Jacoco plugin does provide two totally unrelated functionalities:

- It can generate coverage reports (task type [`JacocoReport`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport.html))
- It can enforce code metrics, e.g. by letting the build fail (task type [`JacocoCoverageVerification`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoCoverageVerification.html))

If the plugin is applied together with the Java Plugin, a task of each of the mentioned types is created, namely `jacocoTestReport` and `jacocoTestCoverageVerification`. As you can see by the name both of them are associated with the `test` task.

However, none of those tasks is automatically included into the regular Gradle `build` lifecycle. The reason for not including the report task is simply because it's not necessary for actually building the actual software. For the same reason, the `javadoc` task is not included in the `build` lifecycle (it might be when creating a javadoc jar). The reason for not including the verification task is trickier, but let's simply quote the docs:

> The `JacocoCoverageVerification` task is not a task dependency of the `check` task provided by the Java plugin. There is a good reason for it. The task is currently not incremental as it doesn't declare any outputs. Any violation of the declared rules would automatically result in a failed build when executing the check task. This behavior might not be desirable for all users. Future versions of Gradle might change the behavior.

You already solved this problem by adding `check.dependsOn jacocoTestCoverageVerification` to your build file. This way, the code coverage will be checked with each build (and fail if not sufficient). Now you want to generate the report in all builds, even if it fails due to unsufficient code coverage. You need to ensure that the report is generated **before** the build might fail. You could use:

```
jacocoTestCoverageVerification.dependsOn jacocoTestReport
```

Answer (score 3):

From the docu https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html
The HTML report is enabled by default. So it is not necessary to put `html.enabled` in the configuration. Also, the docu shows how to specify a destination folder. You could try to set it to some known folder to check if it works at all, e.g. `html.destination file("${buildDir}/jacocoHtml")`. The default report directory where the HTML report should end up is `$buildDir/reports/jacoco/test`
Setting the Jacoco report directory to some explicit value could also help to identify any configuration issues `reportsDir`.

Comment: Thank you @mascha (+1) - but adding `html.destination file("${buildDir}/jacocoHtml")` to my `reports` closure doesn't do anything either. **Interestingly enough** when I invoke Gradle via `./gradlew clean build jacocoTestReport`, if I have adequate test coverage, then the report gets generated! Its only when I run `./gradlew clean build jacocoTestReport` **AND** coverage doesn't meet my 70% threshold that the build just fails and no reports are generated under `build/reports`!!!

Answer (score 3):

in gradle 8.0+  version the syntax has changed
try using below code it works for me

```
jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.required = true
        csv.required = true
        html.required = true
    }
}
```

Comment: life saver! Wasted ages on this, was this in any migration guide?
https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport.html
Note the `destination file('...')` syntax seems to work still.

Comment: https://www.developerscoffee.com/blog/navigating-gradle-version-differences-for-jacoco-and-sonarqube-integration/

I have created detailed post