# gradle build not generating jacoco test report

Tags: testing, gradle, report

In my gradle build script, I have a section which says to generate a test report when I run task : jacocoTestReport

```
jacocoTestReport {
    group = "build"
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination "${buildDir}/reports/coverage"
    }
}
```

When I run the task, it gives me an error :
**Unable to read execution data file ..\build\jacoco\test.exec**
How can I fix this error. When I do gradle build on the complete project, I see test report is getting generated.

Comment: If the problem continues despite of applying the workarounds, you may have a look at my answer on [maven jacoco: not generating code coverage report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395255/maven-jacoco-not-generating-code-coverage-report/71661614#71661614).

Answer (score 1):

You may need to import `jacoco` plugin

```
apply plugin: "jacoco"
```

My gradle.build as follows and working fine

```
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "eclipse"
apply plugin: "idea"
apply plugin: "jacoco"

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
}

test {
  testLogging {
    exceptionFormat = 'full'
    events = ["passed", "failed", "skipped"]
  }
  finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

jacocoTestReport{
  group = "build"
  reports {
    xml.enabled false
    csv.enabled false
    html.destination file("${buildDir}/jacocoHtml")
  }
}
```

Comment: My gradle script already has jacoco plugin.                                                                                           
...
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'war'                                                                                                        jacocoTestReport {
    group = "build"
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination "${buildDir}/reports/coverage"
    }
}

Comment: Specify jacaco tool version as mentioned in https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html