# Maven build and maven-failsafe-plugin - The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye

Tags: java, maven, docker, windows-10, maven-surefire-plugin

I use Docker and https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin for my integration tests.

On my Windows 10 (**after updating to Windows 10 1709**) machine I faced the following error with my `Maven 3.5.0` build:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.20.1:verify (default) on project api: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to D:\Projects\example\api\target\failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C "c:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\bin\java -jar C:\Users\ALEXAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire1232565117555778729\surefirebooter3745527118196863348.jar C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire1232565117555778729 2017-10-19T16-45-23_780-jvmRun1 surefire4633356271541422594tmp surefire_169922891955689988tmp"
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR] Crashed tests:
[ERROR] com.example.domain.api.flag.FlagControllerIT
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:686)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:535)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:280)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:245)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1124)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:954)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:832)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Right now I have no idea what can be wrong, I don't see any failures with my tests.

What can be a reason of this issue and how to solve it?

**UPDATED**

My project have the following configuration:

parent `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=1024m -noverify</argLine>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
```

sub-module `pom.xml`:

```
<profiles>
 <profile>
  <id>local</id>
  <build>
   <plugins>
    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>                            
      <skipTests>true</skipTests>
     </configuration>
    </plugin>
   </plugins>
  </build>
 </profile>
</profiles>
```

As you can see - I added

```
<argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms1024m -Xmx1G -XX:PermSize=1024m -noverify</argLine>
```

to the configuration of `maven-surefire-plugin` to my parent `pom.xml` but it didn't help.

This is output for Maven build with `-e` and `-X`

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:58 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-19T22:27:40+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 62M/1117M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.20.1:verify (default) on project domain: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to D:\Projects\example\domain\target\failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C "c:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\bin\java -jar C:\Users\ALEXAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire7778309393610397922\surefirebooter4888497370312362560.jar C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire7778309393610397922 2017-10-19T22-26-15_682-jvmRun1 surefire8701817832311419883tmp surefire_01518784195718073645tmp"
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR] Crashed tests:
[ERROR] com.example.domain.DecisionCharacteristicIT
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:686)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:535)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:280)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:245)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1124)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:954)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:832)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.20.1:verify (default) on project domain: There are test failures.

Please refer to D:\Projects\example\domain\target\failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
Command was cmd.exe /X /C "c:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\bin\java -jar C:\Users\ALEXAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire7778309393610397922\surefirebooter4888497370312362560.jar C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire7778309393610397922 2017-10-19T22-26-15_682-jvmRun1 surefire8701817832311419883tmp surefire_01518784195718073645tmp"
Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
Process Exit Code: 1
Crashed tests:
com.example.domain.DecisionCharacteristicIT
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:686)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:535)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:280)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:245)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1124)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:954)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:832)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: There are test failures.

Please refer to D:\Projects\example\domain\target\failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
Command was cmd.exe /X /C "c:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\bin\java -jar C:\Users\ALEXAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire7778309393610397922\surefirebooter4888497370312362560.jar C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire7778309393610397922 2017-10-19T22-26-15_682-jvmRun1 surefire8701817832311419883tmp surefire_01518784195718073645tmp"
Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
Process Exit Code: 1
Crashed tests:
com.example.domain.DecisionCharacteristicIT
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:686)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:535)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:280)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:245)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1124)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:954)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:832)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.throwException(SurefireHelper.java:235)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution(SurefireHelper.java:112)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.failsafe.VerifyMojo.execute(VerifyMojo.java:188)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 20 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :domain
```

**This is the full detailed output log:** https://files.fm/u/nfegb38f

**Windows 10 1709 update**

Right now I have thoughts that this issue can be potentially related to the Windows 10 1709 update... I use docker and https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin for my integrstion tests and found the following topic - https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1221  Something is definitely wrong with this update and virtualization...

Comment: Did it get resolved? I am seeing same issues

Comment: I don't know how - but it is working fine right now

Comment: For me, I was getting this error but in the background, process was running with port 5005 as I was running it in eclipse. When I kill the process in console, it started working

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have the same problem and found three solutions which working for me:

#### Problem description

Problem is with maven plugin **maven-surefire-plugin** only in version 2.20.1 and 2.21.0. I checked and you use version 2.20.1.

### Solution 1

Upgrade plugin version to **2.22.0**. Add in **pom.xml**:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.0</version>
</plugin>
```

### Solution 2

Downgrade plugin version to **2.20**. Add in **pom.xml**:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.20</version>
</plugin>
```

### Solution 3

Use plugin configuration **testFailureIgnore**. Add in **pom.xml**:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Had same issue with **Windows 10 1709 update** using _testcontainers_ and _Solution 1 : upgrading surefire & failsafe plugins_ to **2.22.0** worked for us

Comment: Solution 3 ````<testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>```` will ignore test case then what is the used of that one ? That is also ignore assert statement if i am not wrong

Answer (score 21):

I use the maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1, but the forked VM still crashes.
In my case the configuration forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds for the maven-surefire-plugin helps. The default value are since maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1 30 seconds. My project gots very time consuming test and so the forked JVM chrashes. Configure the plugin in the pom with the following property solves the problem.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
                <forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>120</forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Using that property `<forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>120</forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>` solved the same issue I had.

Comment: This also solved my problem. The growing number of test classes led to the problem, I think.

Comment: Last time my test crashes again, also with the property <forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>120</forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>. But I found new properties to fix the crash under following link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260057/the-forked-vm-terminated-without-saying-properly-goodbye-vm-crash-or-system-exi

Answer (score 3):

I'm also have error like that, related with forkstarter on the surefire plugin
maybe you can try add this on your `pom.xml`

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>--add-modules java.base ${argLine} -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
                <forkCount>3</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Hope, this can help you

Comment: Tried this and it's been working.  Hard to say definitively, since the problem is intermittent.

Answer (score 3):

VM can crash because of many reasons. I am highlighting here one more cause it can crash.

I was using maven-surefire-plugin version 2.22.0 with jvm config -Xmx2048m but still it was failing for me.

Cause of failure: 
Accidentally I changed windows command prompt 'window buffer size' width to 2000 instead of changing the height. It causes the vm crashes in my case. When i ran the build using git bash it worked fine. So I able to figure out the issue and reverted the command prompt 'window buffer size' width to default value and it worked fine for me.

Troubleshooting step:

- Use different command tool to verify this issue. like window command prompt, git bash.

Answer (score 2):

I have version 2.22.2 and still get that error. I get pass this by setting the timeout for surefire. So the latest added tests added execution time to exceed the default 30 secs.

```
mvn test -Dsurefire.exitTimeout=40
```

default value for timeout is 30 
https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds

<maven.surefire.plugin.version>2.22.2</maven.surefire.plugin.version>

**Edit:** Actually the logging happening during the tests added up so much time to get timeout. So I changed logging levels.

Answer (score 1):

Try out with Manven OPT parameter

`export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1G -XX:PermSize=1024m -noverify"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please see my updated question. Unfortunately, It still doesn't work.

Comment: I have also added the full detailed output log

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem following solution is working for me:

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>120</forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <properties>
                        <excludeTags>slow</excludeTags>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Ideally you should explain why this solution works - not just provide the answer.