# SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?

Tags: java, maven, jvm, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin

I have problem with throwing this exception in project(several maven modules).
Problem is when i try `mvn clean install` throwing randomly but only in two modules, so now always have build failure. For my work colleagues is working well. Only me showed this error. I try debug mode to see more information, try run [this, but I dont have more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25644234/7236804), but unfortunately, nothing goes forward.

Configuration:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=${project.build.sourceEncoding}</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Tested on:
`Apache Maven 3.5.4`,
`Java version: 1.8.0_172` and older,
`Win 10` and `Ubuntu 18.04`

Comment: I have same issue java 1.8.0_172, on Win 10. Did not have any such issues before on Win7 , java 7

Comment: I not tested on Win7. Which console you use? I use cmder and for one project always building not work by this console, but when i run this same on windows console is working. So try other console