# why is The forked VM terminated fork count necessary on windows and not linux/mac

Tags: java

On windows, it seems necessary to change the POM for tests to pass.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>0</forkCount>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Why does it seem necessary to add these constraints to get a full set of tests passing on Windows JVM, and not MAC or LINUX.

The JVM / maven should behave similarly.

The test execution fails with:

> Surefire fails with the message "The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye

If this really is a deficiency of Windows, then why?

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642673/strategy-for-debugging-surefire-the-forked-vm-terminated-without-saying-properl One of the reasons might be memory allocation. IIRC, hotspot on Windows, depending on the Java version and bitness, might default to a smaller default memory size than on Linux.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/23260057/5221149