# Running testng.xml via pom.xml but build getting failed although no tests fail

Tags: java, maven, selenium, pom.xml

I'm new to automation and don't understand why my build shows failure in the console window when I execute `testng.xml` via `pom.xml` although tests execute fine.

Copying my `pom.xml` and error which might be helpful. If there is something needed, please let me know. Your help would be highly appreciated.

`POM.xml` is as below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.bookbaby.tests</groupId>
    <artifactId>CucumberTestNGMaven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
        <!-- This plugin is used to run java main class file -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- This plugin is used to run java main class file -->
            <!-- <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.bookbaby.executor.RunSuite</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin> -->

    <!-- To run testNg.xml we need below plugin -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.20</version>
        <!-- <inherited>true</inherited> -->
        <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testngSingle.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>suitethreadpoolsize</name>
                        <value>3</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
          </configuration>

          </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Error is below**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO]
    [INFO]------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO]
Building CucumberTestNGMaven 1.0-SNAPSHOT [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources
(default-resources) @ CucumberTestNGMaven --- [INFO] Using 'UTF-8'
encoding to copy filtered resources. [INFO] Copying 0 resource [INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) @
CucumberTestNGMaven --- [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the
module! [INFO] Compiling 41 source files to
C:\Users\Refaque\workspace\CucumberTestNGMavenParallelRunTestng\target\classes
[INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources
(default-testResources) @ CucumberTestNGMaven --- [INFO] Using 'UTF-8'
encoding to copy filtered resources. [INFO] Copying 0 resource [INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:testCompile
(default-testCompile) @ CucumberTestNGMaven --- [INFO] Nothing to
compile - all classes are up to date [INFO]  [INFO] ---
maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test) @ CucumberTestNGMaven
--- [INFO]  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------- [INFO]  T E S T S [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running TestSuite doing set up in RunCukesByFeatureForFirefox
Jul 24, 2017 4:13:08 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake
createSession INFO: Detected dialect: OSS RemoteWebDriver: firefox on
ANY (2f84874a-05a3-48ae-8884-5ca277ff7f54) Hooks Executing
RemoteWebDriver: firefox on ANY (2f84874a-05a3-48ae-8884-5ca277ff7f54)
EXECUTING SCENARIO >>>Successfull login functionality Searching
element By.xpath: //a[@class='wisepop-close'] for presence, will wait
by 30 seconds Searching element By.xpath: //*[@id='login-link']/span
for presence, will wait by 30 seconds Searching element
By.cssSelector:
input[id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_txtUserName"] for
> presence, will wait by 30 seconds Searching element By.cssSelector:
> input[id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_txtPassword"] for
> presence, will wait by 30 seconds Searching element By.id:
> ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_btnLogin for presence, will wait by
> 30 seconds Searching element By.xpath:
> //*[@id='header-menu']/div[2]/a/img for presence, will wait by 30
> seconds
> 
> 1 Scenarios ([32m1 passed[0m) 8 Steps ([32m8 passed[0m) 0m19.141s
> 
> executing after suite [INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0,
> Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 56.446 s - in TestSuite [INFO]  [INFO]
> Results: [INFO]  [INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped:
> 0 [INFO]  [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 01:00 min [INFO] Finished at:
> 2017-07-24T16:13:51+01:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 22M/315M [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test
> (default-test) on project CucumberTestNGMaven: There are test
> failures. [ERROR]  [ERROR] Please refer to
> C:\Users\Refaque\workspace\CucumberTestNGMavenParallelRunTestng\target\surefire-reports
> for the individual test results. [ERROR] Please refer to dump files
> (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and
> [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream. [ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork,
> check output in log [ERROR]
> org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: Error
> occurred in starting fork, check output in log [ERROR] at
> org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:634)
> [ERROR] at
> org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
> [ERROR] at
> org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:279)
> [ERROR] at
> org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:243)
> [ERROR] at
> org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1077)
> [ERROR] at
> org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:907)
> [ERROR] at
> org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:785)
> [ERROR] at
> org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
> [ERROR] at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
> [ERROR] at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
> [ERROR] at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
> [ERROR] at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
> [ERROR] at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
> [ERROR] at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
> [ERROR] at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
> [ERROR] at
> org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307) [ERROR]
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
> [ERROR] at
> org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106) [ERROR]
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863) [ERROR] at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288) [ERROR] at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199) [ERROR] at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [ERROR] at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> [ERROR] at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> [ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [ERROR] at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
> [ERROR] at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
> [ERROR] at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
> [ERROR] at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
> [ERROR] -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of
> the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven
> using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For
> more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read
> the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
> http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException`
```

Comment: Formated XML. When you mis format it, it do not display because browsers try to interpret it as HTML

Comment: did you try to add <forkMode> as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320620/junit-maven-error-occured-in-starting-fork-check-output-in-log? What is the goal of your suitethreadpoolsize? Did you try to comment it out? I mean the full properties definition

Comment: @yohann.martineau 2 - Commented out full properties definition and added <forkMode> but still no luck.

Comment: Did You try to comment out everything also <forkMode> and let testngSingle.xml run in parell by http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-tests ?

Comment: I did try just running testngSingle.xml as TestNGSuite and runs fine. it only gives issues when I run with maven and fails the build.

Comment: I myself got it working by adding <forkMode>never</forkMode> although  yohann.martineau 21 suggested me with "once" which didnt work but "never" worked for me. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @Ref - You might want to post that as an answer to your question and accept it as well. That way the question would get closed.

Answer (score 0):

I myself got it working by adding never although yohann.martineau 21 suggested me with "once" which didnt work but "never" worked for me. Thanks everyone.